# Blazor Server: Protect information in transit with HTTPS: Are WebSockets not secure enough?

Tags: websocket, signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor Server development is great! One of my concerns is with the security of data being sent through SignalR/WebSockets.

From my understanding the communication between client and server is:

1. Action is taken by user e.g. clicks button
2. Javascript innovates the WebSocket communication with my server
3. Server responds with **data** that I've returned
4. Javascript changes the page (DOM)

From Chrome developer tools I can see this happening on the websocket i.e. `wss://localhost/_blazor?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX`. As the websocket is `wss://` I thought communication was secure and ensured *integrity and confidentiality* e.g. man-in-the-middle attacks etc

**So why has Microsoft advised to "Always user HTTPS" in their Blazor Server Threat Migration documentation?**

> **Protect information in transit with HTTPS**
>
> Blazor Server uses SignalR for communication between the client and
> the server. Blazor Server normally uses the transport that SignalR
> negotiates, which is typically WebSockets.
>
> Blazor Server doesn't ensure the integrity and confidentiality of the
> data sent between the server and the client. Always use HTTPS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/server/threat-mitigation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#protect-information-in-transit-with-https

Comment: The warning is just general text. The templates by default turn on HTTPS so you will be secure, but if you write your own app from scratch you might not turn on HTTPS so it's just warning you to turn it on.

Comment: Thanks. After reading your message I have read the text completely differently. I started with a new Blazor Server project (through VS) which as you said is secure by default.

Comment: Also, I didn't realise that HTTPS is used over WebSockets for handshakes etc. I thought these were separate layer 7 protocols, which were secured by TLS/SSL. I'll have to carry on my reading on how WebSockets communicate through HTTPS.

Comment: WebSockets is an extension of HTTP/1.1 so if you use http it uses http, if you use https it uses https.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Brennan for answering my question in the comments.

> **So why has Microsoft advised to "Always user HTTPS" in their Blazor Server Threat Migration documentation?**

The warning is just general text. The two statements on the documentation are independent of each other.

The below explains the mechanism Blazor Server typically uses for communication between client and server i.e. WebSockets

> > **Protect information in transit with HTTPS**
> >
> > Blazor Server uses SignalR for communication between the client and the server. Blazor Server normally uses the transport that SignalR negotiates, which is typically WebSockets.

The below states you should always use a secure protocol when communicating between client and server i.e. HTTPS

> > Blazor Server doesn't ensure the integrity and confidentiality of the data sent between the server and the client. Always use HTTPS.

I assumed Microsoft was referring to using standard API (HTTP/2) endpoints to ensure integrity and confidentiality. As Brennan pointed out - WebSockets is an extension of HTTP/1.1, and thus can use HTTPS.

Hopefully, this helps people in the future.